# Rails - Polymorphic has_many :through with model not building on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

My has_many :through model (Posting) is not building an object on creation of the primary associated object (Post). How can I build the relationship on creation?

Models:

```
class Post
  has_many :postings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :postings, source: :postable, source_type: "Product"
  has_many :Items, through: :postings, source: :postable, source_type: "Item"
end

class Posting
  belongs_to :postable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :post
end

class Product
  has_many :postings, as: :postable
  has_many :posts, through: :postings
end

class Item
  has_many :postings, as: :postable
  has_many :posts, through: :postings
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "postings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "postable_id"
    t.string "postable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "post_id"
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_postings_on_post_id"
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "slug"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Console:

```
Post.create(title: "Foo", product_id:3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):12
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'product_id' for Post.)
```

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: what is the schema of Post?

Comment: @Nezir have added Post schema to my question.

Comment: great and you dont have product_id as reference inside Post schema? What result you get when just try to use line like: Post.create(title: "Foo")

Comment: I don't have any references in Post schema, do I need to add them to the Posting schema? Running that in console succeeds and adds a new Post, but a new Posting doesn't get created: ["title", "Foo"], ["slug", "foo"]], [["created_at", "2018-10-01 05:29:11.276173"], ["updated_at", "2018-10-01 05:29:11.276173"]

Comment: In this case you are just creating Post with title, you dont create any Posting. In your controller after @post.save you should create also Posting like Posting.create(@post.id, and postable type),  you need to provide also postable_type. In general you model associations is a bit weird....

Comment: Yes, I think you're right - would it be best to call @post.build_postings? I've tried to stick to Rails conventions, from this reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/polymorphic_associations.html

Comment: Yes that could be also solution, try, do experiment, you can handle it, just investigate and try.